# UIScrollView can't recognized selector setMaximumZoomScale:

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I created three files: `MyViewController.h`, '`MyViewController.m, MyViewController.xib. In the`xib` file I created one UIScrollView as the root level element and made all necessary connections to its file owner.

In my `.m` file, I overwrite the `loadView` method to set some additional properties of the ScrollView.

```
-(void)loadView{
   [super loadView];
   UIScrollView *tmp = (UIScrollView *)[self view];
   [tmp setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];      // crashed here
}
```

However, the code  crashed at the last line of the function, the log said:

```
-[UIView setMaximumZoomScale:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cda5d60
```

It seems that `tmp` was recognized as a `UIView`, not a `UIScrollView` despite the explicit cast. It's my understanding that `[super loadView];` will load the view from the xib file and set the view of the ViewController. It didn't help even when I moved the crashed line of code to the `viewDidLoad` function.

Edit:

I found similar pattern in Apple's documentation [site:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW1)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;

  tempScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280,960);

}
```

Edit 2:

I somewhat narrowed the problem. Now I've moved the code that casts `[self view]` to `viewDidLoad`, and the error occurs only when I override `loadView`. If I add

```
-(void)loadView{
  [super loadView];
}
```

The error will occur. If I delete these three lines, no error. But isn't the call to super totally the same as not overriding at all? Why the difference?

Comment: where you create UIScrollView ?

Comment: If you're loading from a nib usually you don't override `loadView`. Usually this stuff is set up in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: UIScrollView is created in the xib file. I use standard steps to create a view from xib file.

Comment: I tried moving the crashed line of code to `viewDidLoad`, the error's still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the connections inspector for the connections to files owner is like this or not for scroll view...

See the below picture...

[image]

Then place your code like this in viewDidLoad...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;
    [tempScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];

}
```

This is working fine for me.

Edit 2:

```
-(void)loadView{
    [super loadView];

    UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;

    tempScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,960);
    [tempScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [tempScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];

}
```

This is also working fine for me.

Comment: By default, the files owner contains view which is of type UIView,and UIScrollView is derived from UIView only. So it is better to create another iboutlet for the scroll view to access it.

Comment: Please see my edit. I found Apple use the cast to access the ScrollView, so this should not be a problem(at least not the only one).

Comment: The connections are made. And I narrowed down the problem a bit, see my edit 2 please. Could you test if your code works if you add -(void)loadView{
  [super loadView];
} to the .m file?

Comment: The problem is that your view object isn't a UIScrollView; casting it that way does not make it one.  Try setting a breakpoint and type `po [[self view]class]` to see what it actually is.  This is almost certainly a misconfiguration in Interface Builder.